# ERROR: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached. Further errors for this INPUT function will not be printed

Tags: sql, sas

While using the code able I'm getting an error message as below and also I'm getting the output table.

```
 input(put(serv_to_DT_KEY,8.),yymmdd8.) 
between datepart(D.throughdate) 
and datepart(intnx('day',d.throughdate,31))
```

> Error: INPUT function reported 'ERROR: Invalid date value' while processing WHERE clause.
> ERROR: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached.  Further errors for this INPUT function will not be printed.

Could you please help

Comment: Post the actual log please, it highlights where the error may be. There are too many possibilities with this code and we don't have any data to test it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a true error, exactly; it's a data error, which SAS will let by.  What it's saying is the value in serv_to_DT_KEY is not a valid yymmdd8 for some records.  (The rest of the message, about "limit set by ...", is just SAS saying it's only going to tell you about 20 or so individual data errors instead of showing you every single one, so your log isn't hopeless.)

To fix this you have several options:

- If there is a data issue [ie, all rows *should* have a valid date], then fix that.
- If it's okay that some rows don't have a valid date (for example, they might have a missing), you can use the `??` modifier in the informat in `input` to tell it to ignore these.

Like this:

```
input(put(serv_to_DT_KEY,8.),?yymmdd8.) 
between datepart(D.throughdate) 
and datepart(intnx('day',d.throughdate,31))
```

Comment: which i use the code that you provided with ?? I'm getting error as below     and measureyear=2021 AND
36         input(put(serv_to_DT_KEY,z8.),yymmdd8.)>='01jan2021'd
37           and input(put(serv_to_DT_KEY,8.),??yymmdd8.)
                                               _
                                               22
                                               200
ERROR 22-322: Expecting a format name.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.

Comment: @Manoj Turns out SQL where only uses one `?` not two - edited.  (Two is correct for data step `if`).